# How exactly works this XPATH expression defined on the WSO2 iterate mediatior?

Tags: jakarta-ee, wso2, esb, wso2-esb

I'm studying the WSO2 EIP patterns and I have some doubts reading the official documentation of the **splitter** pattern (https://docs.wso2.com/display/IntegrationPatterns/Splitter)

From a theoretical point of view it is clear to me, I have some doubts about the implementation proposed by the example.

It is defining this proxy containing a sequence implementing the **splitter** pattern:

```
<definitions xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
   <proxy name="SplitMessageProxy" transports="http https" startOnLoad="true">
      <target>
         <inSequence>
            <log level="full"/>
            <iterate xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"
                     preservePayload="true"
                     attachPath="//m0:getQuote"
                     expression="//m0:getQuote/m0:request">
               <target>
                  <sequence>
                     <send>
                        <endpoint>
                           <address uri="http://localhost:9000/services/SimpleStockQuoteService"/>
                        </endpoint>
                     </send>
                  </sequence>
               </target>
            </iterate>
         </inSequence>
         <outSequence>
            <drop/>
         </outSequence>
      </target>
      <publishWSDL uri="file:repository/samples/resources/proxy/sample_proxy_1.wsdl"/>
   </proxy>
   <sequence name="fault">
      <log level="full">
         <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default &#34;fault&#34; sequence"/>
         <property name="ERROR_CODE" expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"/>
         <property name="ERROR_MESSAGE" expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"/>
      </log>
      <drop/>
   </sequence>
   <sequence name="main">
      <in/>
      <out/>
   </sequence>
</definitions>
```

Then this **SOAP request** is sent to the previus proxy:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ser="http://services.samples" xmlns:xsd="http://services.samples/xsd">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ser:getQuote>    
         <ser:request>          
            <xsd:symbol>IBM</xsd:symbol>
         </ser:request>
          <ser:request>           
            <xsd:symbol>WSO2</xsd:symbol>
         </ser:request>
         <ser:request>          
            <xsd:symbol>IBM</xsd:symbol>
         </ser:request>
      </ser:getQuote>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Ok, so the **Iterate mediator** takes each child element of the element specified in its XPath expression and applies the sequence flow inside the iterator mediator...so in this case it is iterating on all the child of the **XPATH expression** defined by: **//m0:getQuote/m0:request** that should be the following XML tag:

```
<xsd:symbol>IBM</xsd:symbol>
```

and

```
<xsd:symbol>WSO2</xsd:symbol>
```

and

```
<xsd:symbol>IBM</xsd:symbol>
```

The doubt on this XPATH expression is:

the XPATH expresion is **//m0:getQuote/m0:request**. Why in this example it is appending the **m0** namespace before the XML element? Why the expression is not something **//ser:getQuote/ser:request** (using the namespace defined inside the XML request coming into the ESB flow)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the namespace that matters, the prefix is just an easy way of referencing a previously defined namespace.

In the request the the prefix ser is defined as

```
xmlns:ser="http://services.samples"
```

In the iterate mediator the m0 prefix is defined as

```
xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"
```

What is actually used when resolving the XPATH expression is the namespace, so both will resolve the same. The prefixes do not have to be similar between different documents, they are only effective within a document. So the m0 prefix is limited to the WSO2 proxy, while the ser prefix is specific for your request.

Answer (score 2):

The namespace m0 defined in Iterate Mediator itself. **xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"**
That's why we use it in Xpath. 
The prefix "m0" doesn't matter, the uri of the namespace does matter.
We could just don't know with what prefix incoming message will arrive.